# Why the IEnumerable.Except method doesn't return any elements?

Tags: c#

I'm generating two `IEnumerable<int>` objects:

```
var listA = model.SelectedFormats.Select(a => a.ID); //values: 1,2,4
var listB = basket.OrderPosition.Select(x => x.BookFormatTypeID); //values: 1,4


var result = listA.Except(listB);
```

but I can't see any results from the `Except` method (the compiler doesn't show even that the 
`result` is)

Comment: What do you mean by "the compiler doesn't show even that the result is"? What are your values? And have you iterated over result - remember LINQ to objects uses deferred execution.

Comment: @Tony - Sounds like your query is resulting in a null result.  Please explain the "the compiler doesn't show even that the result is" statement in detail.

Comment: during the debugging that code, if I move the mouse pointer over the `result` -just nothing shows

Comment: Enumerable.Except should never return null... Is this LINQ to SQL or something like that?

Comment: Please read [this](https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2011/08/08/why-enumerableexcept-might-not-work-the-way-you-might-expect) famous blog to understand the internals of `Enumerable.Except()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IEnumerable.Except()` does not return elements directly, it returns an `IEnumerable` which you can access to iterate over the result.

You could change the last line to

```
#if DEBUG
    List<myResultType> result = new List<myResultType>(listA.Except(listB));
#else
    var result = listA.Except(listB);
#endif
```

This would automatically iterate over the elements and add them to a list, allowing you to inspect the result.

Comment: You should be able to mouse over result in the debugger and expand the enumerable there - @Tony seems to be saying this isn't happening in his case.